# How to replace text in a column

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have a huge file (more than 2 GB) where data is like below.

```
12,324,32342,E:fsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

13,3224,342,E:werwefsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

121,3244,33442,E:,23432,34534,45345,324
```

Here I need to replace all the occurrences of 4th column wherever it is encountering `E:` with a blank space `""`, but wherever it finds a string after `E:`, that should remain as it is.

The expected output would be:

```
12,324,32342,E:fsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

13,3224,342,E:werwefsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

121,3244,33442,,23432,34534,45345,324
```

Comment: I tried the below -
awk -F , '{ if ($4 = "E:") $4="";}1' OFS=, data.final 
but this is replacing all the occurrences of $4 with a blank space.

Answer (score 8):

Your syntax is *almost* right.  To test for string equality in `awk`, use a double equals sign: `==`.  To *assign a value*, use a single equals sign.

So use `if ($4 == "E:")` and you should get the result you want.

The full command would look like this.  Note there is only one character difference from the command you used; that was your only error:

```
awk -F , '{ if ($4 == "E:") $4="";}1' OFS=, data.final
```

To show some different syntax and different approaches, the following versions are exactly equivalent:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$4 == "E:" { $4 = "" }; 1' data.final

awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }; $4 == "E:" { $4 = "" }; {print}' data.final

awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub( /^E:$/, "", $4); print}' data.final
```

Notes regarding the above:

1. If your whole code block is just an if/then, you can just use the condition as a filter for the code block.  Hence `$4 == "E:" {$4 = ""}` is exactly equivalent to `{if ($4 == "E:") {$4 = ""}}`
2. It is good practice to enclose "then" statements in a code block even when there is only one of them, i.e. `if ($4 == "E:") {$4 = ""}` rather than `if ($4 == "E:") $4 = "";`
3. `-F` sets the value of `FS` and `-v` can be used to set the value of any variable before `awk` considers the first line of the first file.  (You likely knew that.)  You can also use a `BEGIN` block to do the same thing; worth knowing for when you want to make the `awk` script stand alone.
4. The reason why `1` prints lines in `awk` is that it is a condition (a filter) which always evaluates to true, and the default action in `awk` when no code block is attached to the filter is to `print $0`.  So `1` by itself is equivalent to `1 {print}` or `1 {print $0}` or just `{print}`.
5. In my last variation, I used a `sub` function to substitute the regex `/^E:$/` (start of string, `E:`, end of string) with `""` in `$4`.

Since the `sub` function returns the number of substitutions that were made (either 1 or 0; use `gsub` to make more than one replacement), you can code golf this problem by adding one to the `sub` function result to ensure you have a pattern that is always true so that the resulting line is printed whether a substitution is made or not.  Here is the code golf version, not recommended for beginner use if you are putting this in a script you will then maintain:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'sub(/^E:$/,"",$4)+1' data.final
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]+,[^,]+,[^ ]+,)E:(,)/\1\2/' file.txt
```

The 4th comma separated field will be made blank if it contains only `E:`.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
12,324,32342,E:fsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324
13,3224,342,E:werwefsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324
121,3244,33442,E:,23432,34534,45345,324

% sed -r 's/^([^,]+,[^,]+,[^ ]+,)E:(,)/\1\2/' file.txt 
12,324,32342,E:fsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324
13,3224,342,E:werwefsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324
121,3244,33442,,23432,34534,45345,324
```

Comment: **s**tream **ed**itor +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file name is `file`, you can try the following:

```
while read -r line; 
do 
var="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 4)";

  if [[ "$var" = "E:" ]]; then echo "$line" | sed s/"$var"/''/g ; 
  else echo "$line";
  fi; 

done < file
```

or:

```
while read -r line; do var="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 4)"; if [[ "$var" = "E:" ]]; then echo "$line" | sed s/"$var"/''/g ; else echo "$line";fi; done < file
```

**Explanation:**

1. `while read -r line;` reads file line by line
2. `var="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 4)";` sores the string at 4th place separated by `,` into variable `var`
3. `if [[ && "$var" = "E:" ]]; then echo "$line" | sed s/"$var"/' '/g ;` if `$var` has string exactly `E:` then `sed s/"$var"/''/g ;` replaces it with blank `""`
4. `else echo "$line";` other wise it prints line as it is

Example **output** (as expected from question):

- `file`:

  ```
  $ cat file
  12,324,32342,E:fsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

  13,3224,342,E:werwefsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

  121,3244,33442,E:,23432,34534,45345,324
  ```
- Running command:

  ```
  $ while read -r line; do var="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 4)"; if [[ "$var" = "E:" ]]; then echo "$line" |sed s/"$var"/' '/g ; else echo "$line";fi; done < file
  12,324,32342,E:fsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

  13,3224,342,E:werwefsdsf,23432,34534,45345,324

  121,3244,33442,,23432,34534,45345,324
  ```

You can also redirect your output to file by using `>> file2` or `|tee file2` at the last of command:

```
while read -r line; do var="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 4)"; if [[ "$var" = "E:" ]]; then echo "$line" |sed s/"$var"/' '/g ; else echo "$line";fi; done < file | tee file2
```